# Why did the movement become jerky after optimization?

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm making a very simple 3D game and the movement just became jerky.

I was using 4 linked lists containing the renderables where each list had a different priority to establish what's in front. It was something I used before with SDL since there was no z axis.

But now I'm using the z axis with OpenGL, having 4 different lists is meaningless, I was just assigning random priority values. So I switched to a single list and the movement became a lot less smooth.

Is this some cache issue? Aren't the values of `x0`, `x1`, `y0`, `y1`, `z0`, `z1` being retrieved from memory now? I tried making them volatile but it didn't help.

There are 2 threads, the logic thread that updates the values and the thread that renders.

Here's the code:

```
typedef struct {
    void *id;
    bool (*render)(void *yourself, game_clock_t time_ms);
    void (*clean)(void *yourself);
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
} Renderable;

typedef struct {
    Renderable renderable;
    Cube cube;
    int x0;
    int y0;
    int z0;
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int z1;
    game_clock_t t0;
    game_clock_t t1;
} Entity;

/* This function is called once for every node in the list */
static game_clock_t frame_time;
static void render_yourself(Node *node)
{
    Renderable *renderable = node->content;

    renderable_lock(renderable);

    if(renderable->render(renderable, frame_time)){
        list_remove_node(&render_list, renderable->id);
        renderable_unlock(renderable);
        renderable->clean(renderable);
        return;
    }

    renderable_unlock(renderable);
}

/* This is the function that draws the entity */
bool entity_render(void *entity_ptr, game_clock_t time)
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float m;
    Entity *entity;

    entity = entity_ptr;

    if(time > entity->t1){
        x = entity->x1;
        y = entity->y1;
        z = entity->z1;
    }
    else
    if(time < entity->t0){
        x = entity->x0;
        y = entity->y0;
        z = entity->z0;
    }
    else {
        m = (float)(time - entity->t0) / (float)(entity->t1 - entity->t0);
        x = entity->x0 + (entity->x1 - entity->x0) * m;
        y = entity->y0 + (entity->y1 - entity->y0) * m;
        z = entity->z0 + (entity->z1 - entity->z0) * m;
    }

    cube_render(entity->cube, x, y, z);

    return false;   
}
```

Why is this happening and what's the solution?

Comment: When you say list, do you mean `std::list` or something else that is actually a linked list? If so change it to `std::vector`, it should speed up things greatly. Linked lists are notoriously cache-unfriendly.

Comment: Profiling Profiling Profiling. Before optimizing you should know your hotspots. Related: GPU Profiling, GPU Profiling, GPU Profiling.

Comment: @nwp I can't use vectors because it's C. I chose linked lists because it makes inserting and removing renderables O(1). I'll try using a simple array and will report back.

Comment: @Samuel I didn't remove all those lists just for performance. I removed them because it's quite ugly to have 4 different lists when a single one will do the job.

Comment: You still need to profile to see what exactly is causing the lag. Linked lists are indeed extremely cache unfriendly and what you have done is to trade ease of inserting with reading speed (if this is really the bottle-neck)